# java.io.StreamCorrupted Exception` in android Client

Tags: java, android, servlets

I am making a connection from Android client to Servlet using url connection. I am sending a string to server on button click.Server is receiving string and able to print it. When the Servlet sends response as a string, The Android Client Client is showing the following Exceoption

 `java.io.StreamCorrupted Exception`
 What can be the reason for such an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception will be thrown if the **expected input stream is not proper**.

**For example:**

If the expected input stream on the ***client side is ObjectInputStream and the server is not writing using ObjectOutputStream***.